# Inner Text not working for Paragraph and Heading HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm newbie to Javascript, I tried the below code, it works fine for `<div>` element but not for `<P> and <h1> elements`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintText(){
        document.getElementById('heading').innerText = 'Hello World';
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="heading"></div> // Works
    <h1 id="heading"></h1> // Not Working
    <P id="heading"></P> // Not Working

    <button type="button" onclick="PrintText()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

When I use `document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML= 'Hello World';` for `<P> and <h1>` elements the above script works(Using `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`)

Why the `innerText` property is not working for `<p> and <h1>` elements?

Comment: `innerText` is implemented in IE and Chrome only.

Comment: @Teemu - Even though innerText not working at IE and Chrome.I already    validated

Comment: Ehh...`innerText` works in IE and Chrome only.

Comment: I wonder whether u validated for <p> and <h1> elements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First suggestion is don't ever put same IDs on multiple elements in same page.

**Why?**

Because when you do `document.getElementById()` browser lookup stops when it finds first element of that ID.

Second suggestion is:

Change

```
innerText
```

To.

```
textContent
```

`innerText` won't work cross browser. Better to use standard way to put text with `textContent`.

Comment: Actaully while writing it in Editor, I removed other 2 elements...I kept  only a single element not all three

Comment: Well that's great! I just wanted to mention what would happen if same id goes on multiple elements. Well it's great to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problematic here is your are using IDs. An ID is something unique. An ID can't be reused. If you want to assign multiple elements at once give them the same class and call them by class in your Javascript code. This should solve your problem as Javascript does not expect multiple elements to have the same ID and so it is only editing the first element.